# Bulk insert into postgres table from python

Tags: python, postgresql, bulkinsert

I want to insert/update values from a pandas dataframe into a postgres table.
I have a unique tuple (a,b) in the postgres table. If the tuple already exists I only want to update the third value c, if the tuple doesn't exist I want to create a triple (a,b,c).

What is the most efficient way to do so? I guess some sort of bulk insert, but I am not quite sure how exactly.

Comment: Don't forget to vote the question as accepted if the solution has worked for you (:

Comment: @borisdonchev I will :) But I didn't have time to test it yet. Thanks for your answer tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your dataframe to a CTE https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html and insert the data from the CTE into the table afterwards. Something like this:

```
def convert_df_to_cte(df):
    vals = ', \n'.join([f"{tuple([f'$str${e}$str$' for e in row])}" for row in df.values])
    vals = vals.replace("'$str$", "$str$")
    vals = vals.replace("$str$'", "$str$")
    vals = vals.replace('"$str$', "$str$")
    vals = vals.replace('$str$"', "$str$")
    vals = vals.replace('$str$nan$str$', 'NULL')

    columns = ', \n'.join(df.columns)

    sql = f"""
    WITH vals AS (
        SELECT 
            {columns}
        FROM 
            (VALUES {vals}) AS t ({columns})
    )
    """
    return sql


df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], columns=['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'])

cte_sql = convert_df_to_cte(df)
sql_to_insert = f"""
{cte_sql}

INSERT INTO schema.table (col_1, col_2, col_3)
SELECT 
    col_1::integer, -- don't forget to cast to right type to avoid errors
    col_2::integer, -- don't forget to cast to right type to avoid errors
    col_3::character varying
FROM 
    vals
ON CONFLICT (col_1, col_2) DO UPDATE SET
    col_3 = excluded.col_3;
"""

run_sql(sql)
```

Comment: What is run_sql?

Comment: It builds a connection to your server and runs the SQL against a particular DB. I haven't defined it, because I don't know what adapters you use and my guess is that you already have built such a function